# Removing unnecessary bits

Tags: java

```
String bin = Long.toBinaryString(i);
System.out.println(bin);
```

Result is: 1100000000000000000000000111010010000**1101110110001**000000001
I want to make new variable and to get only bits from index 37 to 49 or (**1101110110001**), anything else should be removed.
How I can do that?

Comment: Did you try [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substring:

```
String bin = "11000000000000000000000001110100100001101110110001000000001";
String cut = bin.substring(37,50);
```

Note that the endIndex is exclusive, so you have to increment your index by 1.

Further information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-

Answer (score 1):

Try using the java substring() method. So you could do something like :

String reducedBits = bin.substring(37,50);

Note: In substring() method the first value position is inclusive and the second value is exclusive.